# Problem While Installing Synapse Indicator?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, dependencies

I had successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my system. I try to install Synapse Indicator but was unable to do so. I use this link for the installation [Source Link](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/useful-panel-indicators-collection-for.html)

I completed the ppa & update process but got an error while installing the indicator. Here is the error i'm getting :-

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-synapse : Depends: libgranite1 (>= 0.2.0~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I know that this is the dependency issue and i searched that for google too but was unable to get the right information or you can say i tired of doing so.

Kindly, provide me with best answer & some knowledge about these related issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this is going to sound silly...  I got the `ppa:noobslab/indicators` and installed `classicmenu-indicator`. I received basically the same error:

`Unmet dependencies...` blah blah blah and then this:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-synapse : Depends: libgranite1 (>= 0.2.0~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*
```

I removed and cleaned up the install, and then went to the *Software Center* and just downloaded the `classicmenu-indicator`. It works fine. I'm no expert and don't really understand what happened, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found another ppa that worked fine.

First, remove the ppa that didn't work out `ppa:noobslab/indicators`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:noobslab/indicators
```

Next, add the new ppa and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

Log out and back in, and the indicator should be available.